# Como alterar registros de tabela no Banco de Dados depois de 30 dias?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Como eu faço para criar em PHP uma condição que altera o registro de um campo em uma coluna no banco de dados a cada 30 dias?

Exemplo:

```
if ( $valor == 'value_1'){
   // Função que altera o registro
}
```

`value_2` // Valor para o qual deve ser alterado

`meta_value` // Campo que armazena o valor

`wp_usermeta` // Tabela

A cada 30 dias.

Comment: O PHP por si só não vai fazer isso. O que tu pode fazer é criar um script PHP que faça o que você deseja e chame ele pelo agendador de tarefas do Windows ou cron no Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Como o colega [@Diego](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17091/diego) comentou você terá de criar uma tarefa no windows ou no crontab do Linux, lembrando que isto deve ser feito no servidor.
No mais você vai executar o sql abaixo utilizando o sua conexão com o BD

```
Update 
   wp_usermeta
set 
   meta_value = 'value_2' 
Where
  --verifique se há necessidade disto
```

Ademais, como será um script separado do wordpress você poderá usar uma conexão de BD utilizando o comando [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php)